# Your most interesting recording of 2010

Tags: field, recording, best

I've seen this done on alot of photography websites, so I thought it would be nice to try it here.

We have all been busy out recording this year, and I am just wondering what the most Unique and Interesting Sound or Ambience that you have managed to capture.  It can be studio or on-location.  It doesn't necessarily have to be of the best quality recording, just as long as we can hear it.

Just 1 Sound per person.

Here is mine:

[soundcloud]audious/lewes-bonfire-cliffe-society-bishops[/soundcloud]

[Sound Cloud Link](http://soundcloud.com/audious/lewes-bonfire-cliffe-society-bishops)

Made at Lewes Bonfire Celebrations.  Lewes Bonfire is the largest 5th of November Guy Fawkes night in the UK.  They have 6 Bonfires across the town, and this was made at one of them.

There were 3 Bishops on a podium (real people), with one of them reading something over a loud speaker. Whilst they were doing this members of the Cliffe society were throwing bangers AT them.

*EDIT* Hearing some great things so far.  Great work guys.

Comment: Wow, nice capture, @Audious Sound...sounds like a riot, doesn't it? Great thread idea, too, btw!

Comment: Thank you for the compliment @NoiseJockey. It does actually sounds like a riot, but in reality everybody was happy and enjoying themselves.  

Comment: I wish I could add something on here but I think I got my H4n and recorded my first sounds in beginning of this year..

Comment: @stephensaldanha I was really happy with the response of this. So I'll try and do something similar again this december. Although, I must admit I've not had a great deal of time to do much field recording this year.

Answer (score 5):

For me its close between [the implosion of Texas Stadium](http://www.gearslutz.com/board/post-production-forum/483127-tx-stadium-implosion.html) (audio is in the link)

[alt text http://images.blippitt.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/texas_stadium_implosion.jpg](http://images.blippitt.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/texas_stadium_implosion.jpg)

and the timelapsed audio of the trains and traffic in Deep Ellum.

[vimeo]http://vimeo.com/13991711[/vimeo]

http://vimeo.com/13991711

Comment: Sounds like Transformers playing Taiko drums. That was *intense.* Thanks for sharing, Rene.

Comment: it was pretty wild.  the recording doesn't do it justice.  it felt like getting kicked in the chest over and over again.  :)

Comment: Great catch! I experienced my first explosive blast recording in a mine this year. Its hard to describe the physicality of the pressure waves.

Comment: This sounds great? How did you do this timelapse audio effect? It is not time stretched, right? So did you croddfade from one short audio clip to the next? Curious for the answer....

Comment: Thx! its a combination of time compression, layering and crossfading.  I use quickeys to automate the processes, but it still takes about an hour to run everything down.

Comment: That. Is. Awesome. How do you find out about these kinds of events?

Comment: this one was actually a pretty big news item locally.  If you follow the link you'll see what I had to do to avoid the crowds.  Implosions are typically not advertised to the public because they demo companies don't want to have to deal with the liability of crowds.  I need to get in contact with more of those type of guys.

Answer (score 5):

I'm revising my lost lobster recording with this entry -- a dual-contact mic recording of a transmission tower during last night's über strong windstorm here in Los Angeles:

http://soundcloud.com/awfulnicesound/high-tension-tower-in-strong-wind-awfulnice

Comment: Very cool! We've been having some pretty crazy weather here in LA lately.  I missed the last rainstorm and the windstorm, stuck indoors being sick.  Damn....

Comment: @chuck, hope you're on the mend soon, the wind is supposed to last thru tomorrow, I think. That was pretty insane, I had trouble standing against some of those gusts.

Comment: Can I license this sound from you?

Comment: email me: robin at wraughk dot c0m. That is awesome.

Answer (score 4):

the short answer: a geothermal mud pool in Rotorua:

http://soundcloud.com/timprebble/mudpool-original-field-recording

the long answer with photos & processed versions:

http://www.musicofsound.co.nz/blog/favourite-field-recording-of-2010

Comment: Love the Blog Post.  I really like the 2nd example of processing.

Answer (score 4):

An evocative recording I made in the streets of [Jerusalem's Muslim quarter](http://audioloungesound.com/blog/2010/09/field-recording-in-jerusalem/).

[soundcloud]colin-hunter/call-to-prayer-2[/soundcloud]

Comment: I love the sound of the Call to Prayer.  I travelled around Egypt and Jordan during 2009.  During my stay Luxor my hotel had a swimming pool on the roof.  From this point you could hear the sound of the Call of Prayer coming from locations all over the city.  I really wish I had my recording gear with me back then.

Comment: Yeah it can get kinda crazy when you have six or seven mosques in the same area all doing different calls to prayer at the same time! But a single call can be a beautiful sound, especially when it bounces around the local streets and alleys!

Comment: Great stuff. If you want to hear one of my favorite field recordings check out this one of the Blue Mosque. http://www.wanderingear.com/we002.html

Comment: @angrydroid Great recordings! I love the 'Blue Mosque Fajr'. The acoustics are fantastic. I am fascinated by the different call to prayers that can be heard around the world. The mosques in Malaysia and Indonesia are completely different from those I heard in Jerusalem, which in turn are completely different from your recordings at the Blue Mosque. Great stuff!

Comment: I remember these calls. Been there 2008 and I was annoyed, that I didnt brought my recorder with me.

Answer (score 4):

Bending back the metal housing of a hard drive and [playing the platter with a screwdriver](http://www.noisejockey.net/blog/?s=hard+drive+guts).

Comment: You got some excellent sound effects there!

Answer (score 3):

[a cluster of wind driven buddhist praying wheels](http://snd.sc/eWSXly)

[and a walk thru a corridor with hand driven praying wheels.](http://snd.sc/e3cka2)

Both recorded in northern India....

Comment: Really love these.

Answer (score 3):

My favorite recording this year, a little pug named Lola:

http://soundcloud.com/crussom/sets/dogs-superstar-sound-library-preview-crfx-009/

http://www.vimeo.com/15348742

Comment: I love Pugs they're so funny.  It really does sound like a Gremlin :)

Comment: That poor dog sounds like it has breathing problems.

Answer (score 3):

so many favorites... I've had a great year recording all kinds of stuff

I came across this pedestrian suspension bridge in Calgary, hooked up some contact mics to the mainstay cables and had my mind blown.

What you see is what you hear, no effects, just a bit of EQ
http://www.vimeo.com/11176285

Comment: I've come to expect interesting things from you, John, but that was *spectacular*! Very, very nice!

Comment: Wow.  You've captured some amazing sounds there.  I really like what you can do with contact mics.  Great work :)

Answer (score 2):

A steam train pass-by!

http://soundcloud.com/justin-huss/steam-train-pass-by-1 :)

Comment: What a shame the engine passed by so quickly.

Comment: I know, especially when I've waited for an hour to get it!

Answer (score 2):

Water heater turning on
        [Turning on water heater-NORM 01](http://soundcloud.com/shaunkelly/turning-on-water-heater-norm-01) by [shaunkelly](http://soundcloud.com/shaunkelly)

Comment: You have some good sound effects there, Shaun.

Answer (score 2):

My favorite recording was the interview with Pik Botha, the former minister of foreign affairs for South Africa during the Apartheid era.  A lot of interesting things were revealed by the man regarding the time period from 1948 up to 1994.  Fascinating how the public has very little or no idea about what goes on in the hierarchies of government and the hidden agenda's that in some cases spread out over 5 to 10 years before they were achieved!
Unfortunately I cannot disclose any of it with you because of the non-disclosure agreement I had to sign for the shoot which was part of a documentary aptly named "The Plot For Peace" which should be hitting the festivals from March 2011 onwards...

Just thought I'd mention it!  :)

Answer (score 2):

Waiting for the train in Harvard Square subway station...
http://turbulentresonantcolon.tumblr.com/post/595147333/waiting-for-the-train-in-john-harvards-square

Answer (score 2):

The other day I accidentally hit the vibrate button on my razor before picking it up from the toothbrush holder where it resides. I thought it made an interesting sound so I recorded it. I just wish the recording didn't come out so soft. Enjoy!

[Razor vibrations](http://soundcloud.com/mitchell-scott/razor-vibratin)

Answer (score 1):

This song, by me http://soundcloud.com/hi_viz_recordings/indestructable-diamond-sky-craft

Answer (score 1):

http://www.mediafire.com/?x4z2665zcyxlnv4

check it.

tidalminds

Comment: Would you mind rehosting so it can be streamed?

Answer (score 1):

This is a composition I made using a sound synthesized by me. Melody and ambience.
[soundcloud]vibeorigin/structure-from-noise[/soundcloud] 
[Vibe Origin - Structure From Noise @ SoundCloud](http://soundcloud.com/vibeorigin/structure-from-noise)

Answer (score 1):

The great Richard Feynman's voice mixed in with some complimentary sounds.

http://soundcloud.com/pasztor/answer

Answer (score 1):

A dual-mono hydrophone recording of 30 lobsters milling around in an underwater box. And would you believe I deleted it to make room on the card?? It's the "one that got away"…

Comment: I bet that would have sounded amazing.  :(

Comment: that would have been interesting.  where did you put the mics?  what kind of noise did it make?

Comment: @Rene, it was a pretty crazy sound. Very insect-like, pronounced clicking as they moved and climbed over each other.

Comment: :'( [that is all I have to say]